# Make items start from bottom

Tags: html, css

On my web page I have two chats and they don't have the same length. Can I make the chats start from bottom and extend to the top? The chat is going to be for live streams in a obs browser source.

```css
/* Main part beginning */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap');
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end; /* Changed from 'flex-start' to 'flex-end' */
  align-items: center;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  margin-left: 10px;
  flex-direction: column; /* Added flex-direction */
  overflow-y: auto; /* Added overflow-y */
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
.message-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.message-container .logo{
  width: 25px !important;
  height: 25px !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(5px); /* Add this line */
}
.message-container .avatar{
  width: 25px !important;
  height: 25px !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(20px); /* Add this line */
}
.message-container p {
  margin-left: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 300px; 
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
.message-container p span {
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.message-container .name {
  font-size: 19px;
}
.message-container .content {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-size: 18px;
margin-left: 10px
}
/* Main part end */


/* tiers here */

#tier1 .name {
  color: #00A9FF
}
#tier2 .name {
  color: #ee18c3
}
#tier3 .name {
  color: #8b0000
}
#tier4 .name {
  color: #FEF024
}
#tier5 .name {
  color: white
}
#tier5 .content {
  margin-left: -25px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Messages</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="messages" class="messages"></div>
    <div id="messages2" class="messages"></div>
</div>

<script>
  
    const fetchMessages = function(){
        let data = {  data1: [
    {
      "message": "",
      "tierName": "Tier 3",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/453981422156382209/25d5acf1eacfb7eadb9cdbcbf04d6a2d.webp",
      "name": "elow.exe",
      "element": "tier3",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/820357232817340436/b2e76751fa3bd920f7a63b08d62ebf61.webp",
      "name": "gglucabest",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "test",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "sdfsdf",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "dfghdfgh",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "gdfg",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "gfdg",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "dfgdfg",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "rtret",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "sd",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "1",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "2",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "3",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "4",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "5",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "6",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "7",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "8",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
  ],
  data2: [
    {
      "message": "mr",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/WylQDW3-aFE4VRDROVwVl8-GVm6EahILdZfbKxmfC4keMKuRPIUsovfIHlW9vdvzTUZjhlHcLIk=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "OYUN KRALI"
    },
    {
      "message": "me",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/WylQDW3-aFE4VRDROVwVl8-GVm6EahILdZfbKxmfC4keMKuRPIUsovfIHlW9vdvzTUZjhlHcLIk=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "OYUN KRALI"
    },
    {
      "message": "josemg017 meeee",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/7IOq1EI6G7JZPFKjXBYlnoNRYpxuc43IH7MvNWqkeGp9bTXl72pjVB4z2a15ERY_vEni4KLjXA=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "Juana Montoya"
    },
    {
      "message": "alex437362",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/ytc/AIdro_kuM85x0MqX-mAInwUOLmYzJAyZLoTlH_KYPAIVw3Tk7Qv0b5ACsdcUfqCzsTea=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "Jose Lopez"
    },
    {
      "message": "you mr beast",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/WylQDW3-aFE4VRDROVwVl8-GVm6EahILdZfbKxmfC4keMKuRPIUsovfIHlW9vdvzTUZjhlHcLIk=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "OYUN KRALI"
    },
    {
      "message": "josemg017 meee",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/7IOq1EI6G7JZPFKjXBYlnoNRYpxuc43IH7MvNWqkeGp9bTXl72pjVB4z2a15ERY_vEni4KLjXA=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "Juana Montoya"
    },
    {
      "message": "Hello broo",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/UNxu4nH_nkJ9SvRqz-IQUXhSUXgh8O_2zcou5Lmeae83Ta83W3yQ4QcHez-vBw7qlduEatzR=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": " -"
    },
    {
      "message": "mee josemg017",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/7IOq1EI6G7JZPFKjXBYlnoNRYpxuc43IH7MvNWqkeGp9bTXl72pjVB4z2a15ERY_vEni4KLjXA=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "Juana Montoya"
    },
    {
      "message": "what is your group name",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/ytc/AIdro_kuM85x0MqX-mAInwUOLmYzJAyZLoTlH_KYPAIVw3Tk7Qv0b5ACsdcUfqCzsTea=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "Jose Lopez"
    },
    {
      "message": "group name",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/ytc/AIdro_kuM85x0MqX-mAInwUOLmYzJAyZLoTlH_KYPAIVw3Tk7Qv0b5ACsdcUfqCzsTea=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "Jose Lopez"
    }
  ]}
          
            let messagesContainer = document.getElementById('messages');
            messagesContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the container
            data.data1.forEach(function(msg){
              let messageElement = document.createElement('div');
              messageElement.className = 'message-container';
              messageElement.id = msg.element;
              messageElement.innerHTML = `
                  <img src="${msg.avatarUrl}" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
                  <p><span class="name">${msg.name}:</span><img src="${msg.logo}" alt="Logo" class="logo"/><span class="content">${msg.message}</span></p>
              `;
              messagesContainer.appendChild(messageElement);
            });
  
            let messages2Container = document.getElementById('messages2');
            messages2Container.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the container
            data.data2.forEach(function(msg){
              let messageElement = document.createElement('div');
              messageElement.className = 'message-container';
              messageElement.id = msg.element;
              if(msg.element){
               
                messageElement.innerHTML = `
                  <img src="${msg.avatarUrl}" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
                  <p><span class="name" style="color: #00FF00">${msg.name}:</span><img src="${msg.logo}" alt="Logo" class="logo"/><span class="content">${msg.message}</span></p>
              `;
              }else {
                messageElement.innerHTML = `
                  <img src="${msg.avatarUrl}" style="transform: translateY(15px);" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
                  <p><span class="name" style="color: #CCCCCC; /* Add this line */">${msg.name}:</span><span class="content">${msg.message}</span></p>
              `;
              }

              messages2Container.appendChild(messageElement);
            });
        
    };
  
    fetchMessages();
    setInterval(fetchMessages, 1000); 
  </script>
  

</body>
</html>
```

message-container is the container for each message. Div with id messages and messages2 are the chats.

This is how the chat currently looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx3od.png)

And this is how it should look like (edited):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBYkm.png)

Comment: The code shown doesn't appear to demonstrate the output pictured.  Can you update this to a [mcve] which shows the problem?

Comment: `vertical-align:top` to the `.wrapper` ?

Comment: vertical-align:top didn't work, nothing changed but here is a minimal reproducible example https://codepen.io/Elektrodemon/pen/bGJbQOp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use [CSS flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for your "messages" elements.  In particular this combination of styles:

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: flex-end;
```

For example:

```css
/* Main part beginning */
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap');
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end; /* Changed from 'flex-start' to 'flex-end' */
  align-items: center;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  margin-left: 10px;
  flex-direction: column; /* Added flex-direction */
  overflow-y: auto; /* Added overflow-y */
}
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}
.message-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: -25px;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
.message-container .logo{
  width: 25px !important;
  height: 25px !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(5px); /* Add this line */
}
.message-container .avatar{
  width: 25px !important;
  height: 25px !important;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translateY(20px); /* Add this line */
}
.message-container p {
  margin-left: 5px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  max-width: 300px; 
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
.message-container p span {
  font-weight: 700 !important;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.message-container .name {
  font-size: 19px;
}
.message-container .content {
  color: #ffffff !important;
  font-size: 18px;
margin-left: 10px
}
/* Main part end */


/* tiers here */

#tier1 .name {
  color: #00A9FF
}
#tier2 .name {
  color: #ee18c3
}
#tier3 .name {
  color: #8b0000
}
#tier4 .name {
  color: #FEF024
}
#tier5 .name {
  color: white
}
#tier5 .content {
  margin-left: -25px
}

.messages {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Messages</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="messages" class="messages"></div>
    <div id="messages2" class="messages"></div>
</div>

<script>
  
    const fetchMessages = function(){
        let data = {  data1: [
    {
      "message": "",
      "tierName": "Tier 3",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/453981422156382209/25d5acf1eacfb7eadb9cdbcbf04d6a2d.webp",
      "name": "elow.exe",
      "element": "tier3",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/820357232817340436/b2e76751fa3bd920f7a63b08d62ebf61.webp",
      "name": "gglucabest",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "test",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "sdfsdf",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "dfghdfgh",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "gdfg",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "gfdg",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "dfgdfg",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "rtret",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "sd",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "1",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "2",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "3",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "4",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "5",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "6",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "7",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
    {
      "message": "8",
      "tierName": "Tier 1",
      "avatarUrl": "https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/654022997983756328/a_e50819e653858bd938e590b620dea3ae.webp",
      "name": "elektrodemon",
      "element": "tier1",
      "logo": "https://i.ibb.co/ngDdHTV/Bild-2024-02-25-231632291.png"
    },
  ],
  data2: [
    {
      "message": "mr",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/WylQDW3-aFE4VRDROVwVl8-GVm6EahILdZfbKxmfC4keMKuRPIUsovfIHlW9vdvzTUZjhlHcLIk=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "OYUN KRALI"
    },
    {
      "message": "me",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/WylQDW3-aFE4VRDROVwVl8-GVm6EahILdZfbKxmfC4keMKuRPIUsovfIHlW9vdvzTUZjhlHcLIk=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "OYUN KRALI"
    },
    {
      "message": "josemg017 meeee",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/7IOq1EI6G7JZPFKjXBYlnoNRYpxuc43IH7MvNWqkeGp9bTXl72pjVB4z2a15ERY_vEni4KLjXA=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "Juana Montoya"
    },
    {
      "message": "alex437362",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/ytc/AIdro_kuM85x0MqX-mAInwUOLmYzJAyZLoTlH_KYPAIVw3Tk7Qv0b5ACsdcUfqCzsTea=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "Jose Lopez"
    },
    {
      "message": "you mr beast",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/WylQDW3-aFE4VRDROVwVl8-GVm6EahILdZfbKxmfC4keMKuRPIUsovfIHlW9vdvzTUZjhlHcLIk=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "OYUN KRALI"
    },
    {
      "message": "josemg017 meee",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/7IOq1EI6G7JZPFKjXBYlnoNRYpxuc43IH7MvNWqkeGp9bTXl72pjVB4z2a15ERY_vEni4KLjXA=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "Juana Montoya"
    },
    {
      "message": "Hello broo",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/UNxu4nH_nkJ9SvRqz-IQUXhSUXgh8O_2zcou5Lmeae83Ta83W3yQ4QcHez-vBw7qlduEatzR=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": " -"
    },
    {
      "message": "mee josemg017",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/7IOq1EI6G7JZPFKjXBYlnoNRYpxuc43IH7MvNWqkeGp9bTXl72pjVB4z2a15ERY_vEni4KLjXA=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "Juana Montoya"
    },
    {
      "message": "what is your group name",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/ytc/AIdro_kuM85x0MqX-mAInwUOLmYzJAyZLoTlH_KYPAIVw3Tk7Qv0b5ACsdcUfqCzsTea=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "Jose Lopez"
    },
    {
      "message": "group name",
      "avatarUrl": "https://yt4.ggpht.com/ytc/AIdro_kuM85x0MqX-mAInwUOLmYzJAyZLoTlH_KYPAIVw3Tk7Qv0b5ACsdcUfqCzsTea=s64-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj",
      "name": "Jose Lopez"
    }
  ]}
          
            let messagesContainer = document.getElementById('messages');
            messagesContainer.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the container
            data.data1.forEach(function(msg){
              let messageElement = document.createElement('div');
              messageElement.className = 'message-container';
              messageElement.id = msg.element;
              messageElement.innerHTML = `
                  <img src="${msg.avatarUrl}" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
                  <p><span class="name">${msg.name}:</span><img src="${msg.logo}" alt="Logo" class="logo"/><span class="content">${msg.message}</span></p>
              `;
              messagesContainer.appendChild(messageElement);
            });
  
            let messages2Container = document.getElementById('messages2');
            messages2Container.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the container
            data.data2.forEach(function(msg){
              let messageElement = document.createElement('div');
              messageElement.className = 'message-container';
              messageElement.id = msg.element;
              if(msg.element){
               
                messageElement.innerHTML = `
                  <img src="${msg.avatarUrl}" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
                  <p><span class="name" style="color: #00FF00">${msg.name}:</span><img src="${msg.logo}" alt="Logo" class="logo"/><span class="content">${msg.message}</span></p>
              `;
              }else {
                messageElement.innerHTML = `
                  <img src="${msg.avatarUrl}" style="transform: translateY(15px);" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
                  <p><span class="name" style="color: #CCCCCC; /* Add this line */">${msg.name}:</span><span class="content">${msg.message}</span></p>
              `;
              }

              messages2Container.appendChild(messageElement);
            });
        
    };
  
    fetchMessages();
    setInterval(fetchMessages, 1000); 
  </script>
  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks a lot! It worked. I was trying to fix this for 2 days now